# How to use RegularExpression InputScope in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I noticed that one of the 60+ InputScopes for TextBox in Windows Phone 7 is RegularExpression and I want to use. It I could not find any info on who to set the actual regular experssion. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like your idea but as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh393998(v=vs.92).aspx. The following Input scopes are not supported in Windows Phone applications: ApplicationEnd, EnumString, PhraseList, Private, RegularExpression, Srgs, Xml.
[image]